# mlxtend SequentialFeatureSelector give keepdims warning

Tags: data-science, mlxtend, sequentialfeatureselector

I am new to datascience and tried running a tutorial. snippet of code:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_selection import VarianceThreshold
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from mlxtend.feature_selection import SequentialFeatureSelector as SFS

data = pd.read_parquet('files/house_sales.parquet')
X = data.drop(['SalePrice', 'Target']).fillna(-1)
y = data['Target']
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=.2, random_state=42)

sfs = SFS(KNeighborsClassifier(), k_features=10, verbose=2)
sfs.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Produces tons of warnings (seems to be from iteration):

```
[Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Using backend SequentialBackend with 1 concurrent workers.
C:\Users\Asus-PC\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\neighbors\_classification.py:228: FutureWarning: Unlike other reduction functions (e.g. `skew`, `kurtosis`), the default behavior of `mode` typically preserves the axis it acts along. In SciPy 1.11.0, this behavior will change: the default value of `keepdims` will become False, the `axis` over which the statistic is taken will be eliminated, and the value None will no longer be accepted. Set `keepdims` to True or False to avoid this warning.
  mode, _ = stats.mode(_y[neigh_ind, k], axis=1)
C:\Users\Asus-PC\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\neighbors\_classification.py:228: FutureWarning: Unlike other reduction functions (e.g. `skew`, `kurtosis`), the default behavior of `mode` typically preserves the axis it acts along. In SciPy 1.11.0, this behavior will change: the default value of `keepdims` will become False, the `axis` over which the statistic is taken will be eliminated, and the value None will no longer be accepted. Set `keepdims` to True or False to avoid this warning.
  mode, _ = stats.mode(_y[neigh_ind, k], axis=1)
C:\Users\Asus-PC\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\neighbors\_classification.py:228: FutureWarning: Unlike other reduction functions (e.g. `skew`, `kurtosis`), the default behavior of `mode` typically preserves the axis it acts along. In SciPy 1.11.0, this behavior will change: the default value of `keepdims` will become False, the `axis` over which the statistic is taken will be eliminated, and the value None will no longer be accepted. Set `keepdims` to True or False to avoid this warning.
  mode, _ = stats.mode(_y[neigh_ind, k], axis=1)

.... # repeated
```

C:\Users\Asus-PC\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\neighbors_classification.py:228: FutureWarning: Unlike other reduction functions (e.g. `skew`, `kurtosis`), the default behavior of `mode` typically preserves the axis it acts along. In SciPy 1.11.0, this behavior will change: the default value of `keepdims` will become False, the `axis` over which the statistic is taken will be eliminated, and the value None will no longer be accepted. Set `keepdims` to True or False to avoid this warning.

I googled the answer and get that it might be from scipy / numpy modules. It is however unclear on how to set keepdims, as it is not included in the SFS function arguments

Expected example:

```
[Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Using backend LokyBackend with 4 concurrent workers.
[Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done  13 out of  13 | elapsed:   11.5s remaining:    0.0s
[Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done  13 out of  13 | elapsed:   11.5s finished

[2021-02-28 08:34:58] Features: 1/7 -- score: 0.7605911330049261[Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Using backend LokyBackend with 4 concurrent workers.
[Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done  12 out of  12 | elapsed:    7.6s remaining:    0.0s
[Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done  12 out of  12 | elapsed:    7.6s finished
```

Does someone know how to remove the warnings?